# postgresql sync two databases

Tags: postgresql, data-synchronization

I have two databases. One (DB A) is continiously fed with data from a measurement device and contains level 0 (raw) data. The other database (DB B) is an 'extended' database which contains the same data as DB A but also additional tables that contain processed data (serves also as a raw data backup). I now want to syncronize all new data from DB A to DB B without effecting the additional tables on DB B.
I understand that dump and restore would delete the addtional files on DB B. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Dump and restore doesn't wipe anything unless you explicitly tell it to, using parameters like `--clean`.

Comment: You mean you want to set up continuous replication, or you want to copy the raw data once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set things up so that it's happening continuously using [Logical Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html): B would be following all events on A and mirroring all changes.

If that's a one-off task and you're only looking to copy the data over safely, [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) can handle that without wiping anything. Assuming the table name and schema match on A and B and there's a primary key column:

```bash
pg_dump -h your_source_db_host -p your_source_db_port -U your_source_db_user \
--inserts --data-only --on-conflict-do-nothing \
--schema='your_source_table_schema' \
--table='your_source_table_schema.your_source_table_name' your_source_db_name \
|psql -h your_target_db_host -p your_target_db_port -U your_target_db_user \
-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 your_target_db_name &>> your_source_table.clone.log &
```

It's only copying the data and attempting to insert it on B if it wasn't copied already, based on the primary key. Note that if you have the space, it might be way faster to use default `copy` mode aimed at a new table on target, copying the full thing onto the target and resolve the new vs existing locally. Compared to `copy` mode, `insert` mode is pretty slow.

You can also link the source table to be visible on the target using a foreign data wrapper, [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html). With that configured:

```sql
insert into local_table_on_B
select from table_on_A_visible_on_B AS a
--where id not in (select id from local_table_on_B)
--where not exists (select from local_table_on_B AS b where b.id=a.id)
--where created_at>(select max(created_at) from local_table_on_B)
on conflict do nothing;
```